# Enmap (better-sqlite map) doesnt update until application is restarted

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, discord.js

This is a code Snippet from a discord bot im working on

It needs to load up data from an Enmap, adds information to that Array and then pushes it back in.

It successfully pulls that data, does all the transformations and additions, etc
and successfully pushes that data

however, it cant pull the new data until the program is re-started. It gets saved but 
`let locationDataArray = await data.get(locationDataKey);`
doesnt seem to do pull this new version of the map unless the program is restarted

I am fairly stumped

```
const Commando = require('discord.js-commando');
const levenshtein = require('fast-levenshtein');


const Enmap = require("enmap");
const data = new Enmap({
    name:"locationdata"
});

const settingsMap = new Enmap({
    name:"locationSettings"
})

module.exports = class addConnection extends Commando.Command{
    constructor(client){
        super(client, {
            name:"addconnection",
            group:"management",
            aliases:["connect"],
            memberName:"addconnection",
            userPermissions:['ADMINISTRATOR'],
            description:"adds a connection between two zones",
            examples: ['$addconnection <zone1>,<zone2>'],
            throttling: {
                usages: 1,
                duration: 5
            },
            args:[{
                key:'destinations',
                prompt:'what are the two areas you want to connect (seperate them with a comma , )',
                type:'string'
            }]
        });
    }

    async run(msg,args){

        //get our guilds Information
        let guildID = msg.guild.id;
        let locationDataKey = guildID+"_mapData";
        let locationDataArray = await data.get(locationDataKey);

        //Our Guild Settings
        let settingMapKey = guildID+"_setting";
        let settings = await settingsMap.get(settingMapKey);


        //chiefly out npcRoleID
        let npcRole = await msg.guild.roles.get(settings.npcRoleID);

        let connectionArray = await args.destinations.toLowerCase().split(",");

        for(var i = 0; i < connectionArray.length; i++){
            //make sure the item is valid
            var distance = levenshtein.get(connectionArray[i], locationDataArray[0].name);
            var closestDistance = distance;
            var closestWord = locationDataArray[0].name;

            for(var j = 0; j < locationDataArray.length; j++){
                distance = levenshtein.get(connectionArray[i], locationDataArray[j].name);
                if (distance < closestDistance){
                    closestDistance = distance;
                    closestWord = locationDataArray[j].name;
                }
            }

            //make sure all the areas are valid and good
            if(closestDistance < (closestWord.length/2)){
                connectionArray[i] = closestWord;
            }
            else{
                msg.channel.send("those channels don't seem to exist").then( msg => {
                    msg.delete(10000);
                });
                return;
            }  

        }
        //our array of connections now only contains valid options
        //loop over our location data array
        for(var i = 0; i< connectionArray.length; i++){
            for(var j = 0; j < locationDataArray.length; j++){
                //when we hit one of out LDA that has the same name as something in the connectionArray
                //stop add the rest of the connection array to its connections
                if(locationDataArray[j].name === connectionArray[i]){
                    for(var k = 0; k < connectionArray.length; k++){
                        if(locationDataArray[j].name == connectionArray[k]){

                        }
                        else{
                            if(!locationDataArray[j].connections.includes(connectionArray[k])){
                                await locationDataArray[j].connections.push(connectionArray[k]);
                            }

                            //get the role for the connection and the current channel
                            let role = await msg.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === connectionArray[k]);
                            let currentChannel = await msg.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === locationDataArray[j].channelName);


                            //the connection can read but not type in its connection
                            currentChannel.overwritePermissions(
                            role,
                            {
                                'SEND_MESSAGES':false,
                                'VIEW_CHANNEL':true,
                                'READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY':true
                            }
                            )


                            data.set(locationDataKey, locationDataArray);
                            msg.channel.send("Connected "+locationDataArray[j].name+" and "+connectionArray[k]);
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old and I'm hoping you've resolved this issue a long time ago, but for posterity's sake, and because people might find this question later, I'm going to answer it anyways.

The reason this happens is that you're creating a new instance of Enmap in this file, and presumably you have it declared in other files too. This causes a new "client" for Enmap to be created, with its own individual cache, and it's not possible for Enmap to update those instances.

The solution is to either attach your Enmap to a variable you carry around (such as, for example, the Client), or to create a separate node module that you import wherever you need it. Both of those options are described in more details in the Enmap documentation: https://enmap.evie.dev/usage/using-from-multiple-files

Disclaimer: I am the author of Enmap